# How I get a parent value?

Tags: javascript, html, json, canvas-lms

I am coding in Canvas LMS, which means I have limited use of HTML commands in the parent. I created an iframe form and I need a parent's value. For this I put this value in a div. But the command "parent.document.getElementById("nameuser").value" returns: Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin" ERROR. There is another way to get the parent's value?

**Iframe Code**

```
<DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-widht, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:wght@200;300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            var parentURL = window != window.parent ? document.referrer : null;
            var url = parentURL.split('courses/')[1];
            url = url.slice(0,2);
            if(url == "49"){
                $('input[id=turma34]').prop('checked', false);
                $('input[id=turma49]').prop('checked', true);
            }
            if(url == "34"){
                $('input[id=turma49]').prop('checked', false);
                $('input[id=turma34]').prop('checked', true);
            }
            $('input[id=modulo3]').prop('checked', true);
            nameal.value="testenome";
            var quadro = document.createElement("iframe");
            quadro.name="hidden_iframe1";
            quadro.id="hidden_iframe1";
            quadro.style="display:none;"
            document.body.appendChild(quadro);
            //y = parent.document.getElementById('nameuser').value;
            alert(parent.document.getElementById("nameuser").value);
            //x = JSON.stringify(y);
  })
        </script>  
         <style type="text/css">
            body{
                margin: 0;
            }
            form{
                width: 450px;
                margin:auto;
                background-color: rgba(167, 29, 51);
                padding: 10px 20px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                margin-top:20px;
                border-radius: 7px;
            }
            h4{
                color: #fff;
                text-align: center;
                margin: 0;
                font-size: 15px;
            }

            p{
            font-family: 'Helvetica';
            font-style: normal;
            color: #fff
            }

            #desc{
                text-align: justify;
                font-size: 12px;
            }

            textarea{
                 border: 1px solid #fff;
                 background #fff;
                 width:100%;
                 height:50px;
                 border-radius:4px;
                -moz-border-radius:4px;
                -webkit-border-radius:4px;
                box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #333333;    
                -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #333333;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #333333;
            }
            input[type=text]{
                border: 1px solid #fff;
                background #fff;
                width:100%;
                height:30px;
                border-radius:4px;
                -moz-border-radius:4px;
                -webkit-border-radius:4px;
                box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #333333;    
                -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #333333;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #333333;
            }
            #submit {
                border:1px solid #fff;
                background-color: rgba(167, 29, 51);
                border-radius:4px;
                display:inline-block;
                cursor:pointer;
                font-weight:bold;
                font-size:13px;
                padding:6px 10px;
                color: #fff;
                text-decoration: none;
                margin-left: 42%;
                margin-right: 50%;
}
        .tabela{
            text-align: center;
            align-items: center;
            text-decoration-color: #fff;
            color: #fff;

        }

        </style> 
           </head>
    <body>
        
    <form name = "formaval" action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/1/d/e/1FAIpQLSdivzm7jTmYJG3Gg4LR_9XlkCzDX1mxto-7jqlSp4w1KQVgPA/formResponse" method=”POST” id=”contact_form” name=”” class="feedback-form"  target="hidden_iframe1" onsubmit="myButton.disabled = true; return true;" onsubmit="alert('Resposta enviada! Muito obrigado!');"> 
        <div class="c_nome">
        <h4><p>Nome (opcional)</h4></p>
        <input type="text" id="nameal" name="entry.1905947256" > </p>
        </div>
        <h4><p hidden>Turma</p></h4>
        <p hidden><input type="radio" id="turma34" name="entry.629188928" value="34">
            <input type="radio" id="turma49" name="entry.629188928" value="49">
        </p>
        <div class="c_nota">
        <h4><p>Nota do Módulo</p></h4>
        <p id="desc">Considerando conteúdo, dinâmica das aulas, testes e exercícios práticos, de 0 a 10, que nota você daria para esse módulo?</p></h6>
        <p> <table class="tabela" border = "0">  <tr>
            <td>0 </td> 
            <td>1 </td>
            <td>2 </td>
            <td>3 </td>
            <td>4 </td>
            <td>5 </td>
            <td>6 </td>
            <td>7 </td>
            <td>8 </td>
            <td>9 </td>
            <td>10 </td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" required name="entry.1024362957" value="0"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="entry.1024362957" value="1">  </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="entry.1024362957" value="2"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="entry.1024362957" value="3"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="entry.1024362957" value="4"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="entry.1024362957" value="5"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="entry.1024362957" value="6"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="entry.1024362957" value="7"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="entry.1024362957" value="8"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="entry.1024362957" value="9"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="entry.1024362957" value="10"></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div hidden class="c_modulo">
            <h4><p> Módulo</p></h4>
            <p id="desc">Considerando conteúdo, dinâmica das aulas, testes e exercícios práticos, de 0 a 10, que nota você daria para esse módulo?</p></h6>
            <p>     <input type="radio" id="modulo1" name="entry.1084607278" value="M1">
                    <input type="radio" id="modulo2" name="entry.1084607278" value="M2">
                    <input type="radio" id="modulo3" name="entry.1084607278" value="M3">
                    <input type="radio" id="modulo4" name="entry.1084607278" value="M4">
                    <input type="radio" id="modulo5" name="entry.1084607278" value="M5">
                    <input type="radio" id="modulo6" name="entry.1084607278" value="M6">
                    <input type="radio" id="modulo7" name="entry.1084607278" value="M7">
                    <input type="radio" id="modulo8" name="entry.1084607278" value="M8">
                    <input type="radio" id="modulo9" name="entry.1084607278" value="M9">
                    <input type="radio" id="modulo10"name="entry.1084607278" value="M10">
                </p>
            </div>
        <div class="c_justificativa">
        <h4><p>Justificativa</h4></p>
        <textarea name="entry.1092321263":></textarea> <br/>
        </div>
        <div class="c_recomendacao">
        <h4><p>Recomendação</p></h4>
        <p id="desc">De 0 a 10, quanto você recomendaria esse curso?</p>
        <p> <table class="tabela" border = "0"> <tr>
            <td>0 </td> 
            <td>1 </td>
            <td>2 </td>
            <td>3 </td>
            <td>4 </td>
            <td>5 </td>
            <td>6 </td>
            <td>7 </td>
            <td>8 </td>
            <td>9 </td>
            <td>10 </td></tr>
            <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" required name="entry.1797755703" value="0"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="entry.1797755703" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="entry.1797755703" value="2"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="entry.1797755703" value="3"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="entry.1797755703" value="4"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="entry.1797755703" value="5"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="entry.1797755703" value="6"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="entry.1797755703" value="7"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="entry.1797755703" value="8"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="entry.1797755703" value="9"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="entry.1797755703" value="10"></td></tr></p>
        </div>
    </table>
        <div class="c_btn">
            <input class="btn btn-submit" type="submit" name="myButton" id="submit" value="Enviar";this.disabled=true onclick= "alert('Resposta enviada! Muito obrigado!')">
        </div>
        
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PARENT CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $.getJSON("/api/v1/users/self", function(data){
  x = data;
  y = JSON.stringify(x);
  console.log(y);
});
divname = '<div id="nameuser"> <p>' +y+'</p></div>'
              $('#content').prepend(divname);
}
```